# Excel Auto emails

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this excel made up , in which i want to send automatic  reminder email before 15 days & 5 days respectively before the completion date.

I have used (=C2+365)to add one year to column C2 and likewise subtracted 15 and 5 days from Column D2.

[image]

The Task can have different dates. Please advise if this is possible in Excel.

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking? You have a sheet that appears to be working. `Please advise if this is possible in Excel.` In this statement, what does the `this` refer to?

Comment: This refers to  " Sending Auto emails using VBA"

Comment: I do think you need to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
We are trying to help but we cannot read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send mails from an Excel that is closed. Either you always have the Excel open and you macro something that tests each time if now() is bigger that columns E or F...

What you could do is send the mails from your code and hold them in your mailbox until whished day using

```
.DeferredDeliveryTime = Date
```

Base the 'Date' on your columns E and F.

Comment: Hi Jo.Jass,

Thankyou for answering !!

I agree that i should send the mails from code and hold them mailbox until whished day using.

Could please share a code for the same . Making excel generate a email and hold it in outlook 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can either schedule email as @Jo Lass suggested, or set reminders in outlook. Here's the code I wrote, tweak as needed. It will add 2 reminders per task (5 and 15 days before 'to be completed date', dates taken from cells E and F)

```
Sub addReminder()

    Dim objApt As AppointmentItem
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim d, i

    Set objOL = New Outlook.Application

    LastRow = Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        For Each d In Array("E", "F")
            With objOL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
                .ReminderSet = True
                .start = CDate(Range(d & i).Value)
                .Subject = "Task '" & Range("B" & i).Value & "' to be completed on " & Range("D" & i).Value
                .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 0
                .Save
            End With
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```